# Youtube video autoplay is not working on chrome in iphone device

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

```js
if($('.explore-video-btn').length > 0) {
  var video_id = youtube_parser($('.explore-video-btn').attr('data-video-url'));
 }
 
 var tag = document.createElement('script');
 tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
 var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
 firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

 //Holds a reference to the YouTube player
 

 //this function is called by the API
 if(document.getElementsByClassName('explore-video-btn').length !== 0) {
  document.getElementsByClassName('explore-video-btn')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
   onYouTubePlayerAPIReady();
  });
 }

 var player;
 function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
 
  setTimeout(function() {
  
   player = new YT.Player('youtube-iframe', {
    videoId: video_id,
    playerVars: {'rel': 0, 'showinfo': 0, 'ecver': 2, 'autoplay': 1},
    events: {
     'onReady': onPlayerReady,
     'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
   });
   //subscribe to events
   
  }, 200);
 }
 
 function onPlayerReady(event) {
  event.target.mute();
  event.target.playVideo();
 }

 function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
   event.target.stopVideo();
  }
 }
```

I have used youtube API to autoplay video, it works properly on android devices in chrome browser but does not autoplay on iphone devices in chrome browser. I have found the youtube API document warning such as **"Warning: To prevent unsolicited downloads over cellular networks at the user’s expense, embedded media cannot be played automatically in Safari on iOS — the user always initiates playback."**.

The warning says autoplay does not work on safari in ios but not mention chrome in ios. Please help me to find solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's not a browser problem. It's about iOS.

Policies for video Starting in iOS.

> ```
> <video autoplay> elements will now honor the autoplay attribute, for elements which meet the following conditions:
> <video> elements will be allowed to autoplay without a user gesture if their source media contains no audio tracks.
> <video muted> elements will also be allowed to autoplay without a user gesture.
> If a <video> element gains an audio track or becomes un-muted without a user gesture, playback will pause.
> <video autoplay> elements will only begin playing when visible on-screen such as when they are scrolled into the viewport, made visible through CSS, and inserted into the DOM.
> <video autoplay> elements will pause if they become non-visible, such as by being scrolled out of the viewport.
> ```

[See a full list about these restrictions on official site.](https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/)

No you cant from IFrame api:

> Mobile Considerations Autoplay and Scripted Playback The HTML5 
>   element, in certain mobile browsers (such as Chrome and Safari), only
>   allows playback to take place if it's initiated by a user interaction
>   (such as tapping on the player). Here's an excerpt from Apple's
>   documentation:
>
> "Warning: To prevent unsolicited downloads over cellular networks at
>   the user’s expense, embedded media cannot be played automatically in
>   Safari on iOS — the user always initiates playback."
>
> Due to this restriction, functions and parameters such as autoplay,
>   playVideo(), loadVideoById() won't work in all mobile environments.

[From YouTube IFrame Player API official document](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player)

**Conclusion -> No you can't**

Comment: I am using iframe tag and as per the above condition we have to mute the video to make autoplay working which I already did but there is no result.

Comment: I have updated my code above please review it to check if everything is correct.